# why function plotSex has error when knit?

Tags: bioconductor

I try to recreate the last figure in the URL but got. an error.

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'table' in selecting a method for function '%in%': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'colnames': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘colData’ for signature ‘"DFrame"’ –

Would anyone tell me why? I appreciate your help!I am new here so I can't upload the image of error now.
https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2015/BioC2015/methylation450k.html

`plotSex(getSex(GRset, cutoff = -2))`

Comment: you need to at least copy and paste your error message, so someone could give help

Comment: Sorry for did not post the error because when I knit, Rstudio did not allow me to copy the error.

Comment: check if this website could help https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9135133/#9135155

Comment: Thank Sammy! I appreciate your help. I was busy this week with my project.